# Starting a down counter after an update on a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I am counting some parts on a production line and sending the parts count information to a table in SQL.
Each part is passing in front of a sensor in roughly seconds of period.(the time elapsed from first part passing the sensor to second part is 10 seconds)

The production line engineer wants to be notified when this period(10 seconds) is exceeded.
So lets say if the period of update in the sql table exceeds 10 seconds by 100%(which is 20 seconds) I need to find a way to notify the engineer.
I guess I will need a counter to be set 20 seconds in this case(which will be parameterized later) and call a stored procedure when the counter counts down to zero. If during this period of 20 seconds another update occurs I will need to set the counter value again to 20 seconds.
But I could not figure out a way of doing this through stored procedures or triggers.
Any comments are welcome.

I did not try anything yet and I will wait for different ideas to implement the best one that fits my requirements.
I do not have much experience on SQL Triggers and how to use them properly yet and trying to gather information at the moment.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Triggers are often product specific, and you'll probably need some other product specific functionality as well.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server